# Maximum distribution for forming triangles

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Okay, so I have the following problem. We take turns breaking a piece of spaghetti stick. They always break the stick in two pieces and always break the largest remaining piece. There is a stick of length one which we break $n-1$ times to create $n$ pieces. What is the maximal way to break this stick so that the maximum number of triangles can be formed?

I have a conjecture that the best way to break the stick for forming triangles is to have each break being as close to half as possible. For example for $n=4$ some breaks could be:

$0.5-0.5$ for break one

$0.25-0.25$ for break two

$0.125-0.125$ for break three

Which would yield four pieces, $0.125, 0.125, 0.25,$ and $0.5$. You can create a triangle with any of these four pieces, they can be combined in any way. We are then trying to find the distribution where the highest number of triangles can be formed.

Does anyone see a strategy which would work or perhaps the answer for the case of $n=4$?

Comment: Do sticks of length $a,b,a+b$ form a triangle?

Comment: Yes, they should because in an actual case the numbers are continuous and not perfectly broken so it's safe to say that $a, b,$ and $a+b$ would work.

Comment: I am sorry but your "maximal number of triangles" is not clearly defined. Do you mean that among the $n$ pieces, you consider all the sets of 3 pieces, decide if yes or no you can build a triangle with these three pieces, and try to have the maximal number of "yes" ?

Comment: Surely the best way to break them is into $n$ equal pieces (ie. you break off $(n+1-k)^{-1}$ of the longest remaining piece on the $k$th break). Then any set of $3$ pieces form a triangle. Of course, this isn't the only solution, but is the easiest to think of.

Comment: Yes, Jean Marie this is what I mean, but remember that there will not be three sets there will be $n+1$ pieces because in each case we break the longest piece into two remaining pieces.

Comment: If you had to break the shortest remaining piece each time instead, then your solution might be correct.

Comment: I have not said that that there are three "sets". But the remark by @Shuri2060 is in fact an answer that closes the discussion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to break them is into $n$ equal pieces (ie. you break off $\frac{1}{n+1−k}$ of the longest remaining piece on the $k$th break). Then any set of $3$ pieces form a triangle. This isn't the only solution, but is the easiest to think of.

---

On the other hand, if the question were changed slightly so that you had to break the shortest remaining piece each time instead, then your solution is correct. This can be shown inductively by considering what happens on each break.

Each time you break a piece into non-equal proportions, if this isn't the last break, then you will not be able to form a triangle using the larger piece and two pieces which are later created from the shorter piece (triangle inequality). If this isn't the first break, you won't be able to form a triangle using one of your pieces from earlier (no matter your method of breaking beforehand), the larger piece and a later created shorter piece.

Therefore, you need to break the piece into half each time for the maximum number of triangles under these restrictions.